# Add property in Django many to many relation

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have the following Django models:

```python
class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()

class Course(models.Model):
    lessons = models.ManyToManyField(Lesson)

class User(AbstractUser):
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Lesson)
```

I have a route /courses/course_id that returns a course details including an array of lessons (using Django Rest Framework)

How can i return in the lessons object an additional attribute favorite based on my users favorites.

I attempted the following:

```python
course = self.get_object(course_id)
favorites = request.user.favorites

for lesson in course.lessons.all():
    if lesson in favorites.all():
        lesson.favorite = True

serializer = CourseDetailSerializer(course, context=serializer_context)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

But when returning it doesn't work:

> (django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `favorite` is
>   not valid for model `Lesson`.

My serializers:

```python
class CourseDetailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    lessons = LessonListSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('id', 'lessons', 'name', 'title')


class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'duration', 'favorite')
```

Comment: I think you should add a new Boolean Field `favorite` to the Lesson model.

Comment: I don't think that will help this is just poor database design in the first place making this overly difficult. The first answer details that I was about to recommend the same thing. I try to avoid ManyToMany as much as possible.

Comment: **`request.user.favorites.all()`** would return all `favorites` instances related to logged-in user. Is that you want? I couldn't understand your requirement

Comment: @MitchellWalls what db design would you suggest ? The need is for a user to have favorite lessons.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot add properties to objects if they are not defined, like here:

```
lesson.favorite = True
```

When you create m2m relation:

```
favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Lesson)
```

... django creates virtual model that simply stores pairs of primary keys from both models. This relation could look like this in database:

```
  id  | user_id       | lesson_id 
------+---------------+----------
  151 |            11 |     3225
  741 |            21 |     4137
```

What I think you want to achieve is to add extra information about this relation.
Therefore you need to create intermediary model with that extra field, i.e:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
     favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Lesson, through='UserLessons')

class UserLessons(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     lesson =  models.ForeignKey(Lesson)
     favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: I think to help out further this will also need a intermediate table for course and lesson. It will help for the situation that the Course teaches the same lesson more than once. It would also be smart to have a unique together meta on that as well.

Comment: This seems like a good solution, and I tried implementing it in a similar problem I have. But I haven't been able to figure out how to access the extra property on the link-table.

With the code you have here user.favorites.all() will list all the Lessons the user has, but  that doesn't let you access the favorite-flag.

Answer (score -1):

Your `lesson`model doesn't include a `favourite` boolean, so it isn't able to set it when you call `lesson.favorite = True`

If you want to get rid of the error, try:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    favorite = models.BooleanField(initial=False)
```

Although it appears that the lessons aren't user-specific. So this solution might not be what you are looking for, because it will set a Lesson's "favourite" field to be true for ***all*** users if only ***one*** user sets it as a favorite.

Comment: the problem is that I don't want the favorite field to be stored with the lesson but with the user (it's a user that has favorite lessons)